# Why does my Android phone charger cause my (powered-off) stereo receiver to make a high-pitched chirping sound when plugged into the same powerstrip?

Tags: power-supply, noise, receiver

After days of scouring my apartment, wondering if I’d developed another pitch of tinnitus, trying to figure out what the hell was making that infernal noise, I finally isolated it to this.

- Onkyo receiver is plugged into a powerstrip
- Android phone charger and cable plugged into same powerstrip.
- it’s an old powerstrip. I got it at a flea market for a buck. Until this, it’s worked great.

This causes a continuous high-pitched chirping sound, from the receiver—not the speakers. It’s quiet enough to make me wonder if it’s really there, but loud enough to drive you crazy.

Why must these devices torture me so?

Comment: Your phone charger is trashing the power line, and the receiver's power supply responds to the trash. Perhaps you need newer electrolytics in the receiver.

Comment: perhaps the Android charger has lots of ultrasonic pulses that down-mix with the Onkyo power supply switcher and cause the magnetic chokes to chirp.

Comment: ANSWER: Some or all of the equipment was made in Asia by people who built to a price for people who did not care enough about quality to either specify properly it or test to ensure standards were met. Standards compliance marks were applied that meant nothing and the buyer/reseller made his buck. There may be ways of working around the defects in the current equipment but, odds are, finding something that happens to work or buying an overpriced brand that can afford to stand behind its name may be easier and / or cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

(Do not be cruel. I have tinnitus. It is like your worst nightmare come true.)

This could be magnetostriction, or clashing PWM supplies. The chirps could be core noise or frequency ratios mixing at a core.

Suggest power strip with CM chokes as EMI filters. Pay the cost. Fix the problem.

Comment: I am not being cruel. I have it too. It was really bad—doctor removed a polyp from my eardrum. Still there, but not as bad. Watch your coffee intake.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Also try stretching the muscles in your jaw and neck. Roll your head around, and take the time to let them release. Sometimes I wonder if its a series of tight muscles ultimately pulling on the eardrum muscles. Yoga also helps if you have the time.

Comment: I meant no harm with the tinfoil hat comment, and I apologize if it came across as insensitive.

Comment: @TylerStone Duly noted. Thank you.